# DataGrip MySQL 8 is slow when compared to TablePlus

Tags: amazon-aurora, datagrip

I have cities table with 145,338 entries. When I do `select count(*) from cities;` using DataGrip it is taking 5 seconds. The database is hosted on AWS `rds.amazonaws.com`. However the database when I query using TablePlus it returns the count in 359 ms. I have MySQL Aurora as the driver for DataGrip. I also tries MySQL 8. Both take around the same time. The main issue I faced was during data import. Importing the cities from sql dump was taking forever using DataGrip. It took around 10 minutes to import using TablePlus. Any idea why DataGrip is slow and how to speed up?

Comment: From your Aurora MySQL 8 instance - Additional DB information request, please. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide import speed improving suggestions.

Comment: Speaking of the DataGrip execution time, each case (query performance, import duration) needs to be analyzed individually. Therefore, please run the problematic query, collect the database log from Help - Show SQL Log in Files, and post it on our tracker

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=DBE

Comment: What's the way you run import in DataGrip IDE? Is it via Run Configuration or via opening file and running its contents?

Comment: I am using `SQL Scripts > Run SQL Scripts` option to run from file.

Comment: Have you tried native utils like mysqldump/mysql?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, DataGrip is experiencing performance issues when executing queries.

Follow the issue [DBE-12832](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-12832/Slow-queries-in-datagrip-fast-normal-in-pgAdmin-other-GUI) to stay updated.